# python opencv: cannot save the images to the video

Tags: python, opencv

I have a series of images and I like to create a video based on them, and I wrote the following codes:

```
import cv2
img=[]
for i in range(1,285):
    img.append(cv2.imread(str(i)+'.png'))

for j in range(1,285):
    height,width,layers=img[j].shape
    video=cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi',-1,1,(width,height))
    video.write(img[j])

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

and the error was:

```
AVF: AVAssetWriter status: Cannot Save
mMovieWriter.status: 3. Error: Cannot Save
```

where was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a new `Videowriter` for every frame you want to write, so you are not actually adding frames to the video, but you keep making new videowriters where you add one frame. This probably results in a save error. Try this:

```
# Create the videowriter with the right parameters
height , width , layers =  img[0].shape
video=cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi',-1,1,(width,height))

# Loop through all you frames and add each frame to the video
for j in range(1,285):    
    video.write(img[j])

# Cleanup and save video
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

See [this OpenCV C++ tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html#videowritehighgui) for more info.

Comment: thx but it still doesn't work, and I think list object does not have a shape method right? I was thinking maybe VideoWriter only operates on those images with the same shape, when the images have different shape maybe they cannot be used to create a video...

Comment: Make sure that the video does not yet exist. Also, try different codecs. Lastly, try different input methods. Make a white and black image using OpenCV and alternate between the images and save the video, this should work. If all this does not work, try it on a different system. I believe `AVAssetWriter` is iOS, so it could be that writing video like this is not supported on that platform (can't test that for you).